# Water Ripple Effect Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to find out a way to implement a water ripple effect on a bitmap. I have just idea and I didn't start coding yet. I done some research but I can't really find a good way to implement this so far. Do you guys have any clue on this ? openGl can do this ?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. Working out of the box library there http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html

Just follow their examples.

BTW, was curious and kept searching, there´s a bunch of links in this question [Android - How to apply diffenernt Image Effects on bitmap like sepia, blackand white, blur etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292146/android-how-to-apply-diffenernt-image-effects-on-bitmap-like-sepia-blackand-w)

Answer (score 0):

Yes openGL can do it. You can use Android OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0 Engine - [Rajawali](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali) ,this engine support [Virtual Reality](https://github.com/Rajawali/RajawaliVR) as well as [Augmented Reality](https://github.com/Rajawali/RajawaliVuforia) .

You can use Rajwali to create water ripples as shown in this example :-

https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/rajawali3d/examples/examples/effects/TouchRipplesFragment.java

You can download and see example from [PlayStore](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiyvsPfyZfMAhWkUqYKHcehBD4QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials%26hl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNG1PFcOYd4nynyxOwTn3-H-mP9Eiw&sig2=7YrdZit7qQqu6Qxpc5wUDw)

Comment: TouchRipplesFragment contains the commented code .can u help