# Android Thermal Camera Mimic

Tags: android, camera

I am working on an application that contains a `viewfinder` and I want to mimic a thermal camera. What is the best way to mimic this without any additional hardware?

Comment: You kind of need hardware for that.  Phone cameras don't capture infrared.

Comment: If you mean mimic as in create the illusion then you could take a look at some of these answers :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292146/how-to-apply-different-image-effects-filters-on-bitmap-like-sepia-black-and-w

Comment: You could play around with [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/) for image processing, maybe you can find an effect that does what you want. - can't help much with that though, I only used this in C++ before